# Specify the type residing in a specific address

Tags: c, bash, memory-management, reflection, linker-scripts

I use Bash to get a c program variables' addresses. How to know if the address is related to an integer, float or double variable?

Comment: There is no way to know that, at least not without debugging symbols.

Comment: Does this exist in any other language? How?

Comment: even built in C functions, such as `printf()`, `scanf()` et. al, parse the _format specifiers_ (i.e. such as "%s, %f, %d") to know what is being passed.  Agree with @Jocke, there is no other way but to pass an argument saying what they are.

Comment: If you use gcc, you can compile with the `-g` flag to compile with debugging symbols.  Debugging symbols are extra data in the binary which contains information of what type variables are, what their names are etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mentioned you can't get the type unless you have debugging symbols.  But if you do have the symbols then you can use GDB.  Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int i = 42;
static float f = 42.1;
static double d = 42.2;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("i=%d, f=%f, d=%f\n", i, f, d);
    return (0);
}
```

If you compile it as follows:

```
gcc -g -o types types.c
```

You can then get the type of variables like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo ptype i | gdb --silent types
Reading symbols from /home/ubuntu/types...done.
(gdb) type = int
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo ptype f | gdb --silent types
Reading symbols from /home/ubuntu/types...done.
(gdb) type = float
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo ptype d | gdb --silent types
Reading symbols from /home/ubuntu/types...done.
(gdb) type = double
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

---

If you only have the symbol table and not full debugging information, i.e. the binary was compiled with `-g`, then processed by `strip -d`, then the best you can do is get the size of the given object using binary dump utilities such as `nm`, `objdump` or `readelf`.

Using `nm`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ read addr next_addr <<< $(nm -n types | grep -A1 ' i$' | cut -d' ' -f1)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "ibase=16; ${next_addr^^} - ${addr^^}" | bc
4
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ read addr next_addr <<< $(nm -n types | grep -A1 ' f$' | cut -d' ' -f1)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "ibase=16; ${next_addr^^} - ${addr^^}" | bc
4
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ read addr next_addr <<< $(nm -n types | grep -A1 ' d$' | cut -d' ' -f1)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "ibase=16; ${next_addr^^} - ${addr^^}" | bc
8
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

This works as follows:

- `nm -n` lists the symbol table with addresses in numerical order
- `grep -A1 ' i$` filters the symbol we are interested long with the immediately following line.  Note this is a regular expression search constructed to find exactly the symbol `i` and nothing else
- `cut -d' ' -f1` lists just the addresses
- `read addr next_addr` puts the addresses into two variables
- The expression piped into `bc` then calculates the difference between the address we are interested in and the immediately following address.  Note the addresses are in hex, so we need to tell `bc` that with the `ibase` parameter.  Also the `${var^^}` bash expansion converts the hex digits a-f to uppercase as `bc` requires this.